# read/write raw data with QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt

I am fairly new to QDataStream and Socket programming, and what I want to do is to simply send a quint32 header value (four bytes) from client to host. But I am having some trouble with QDataStream.

```
QByteArray data;
QDataStream ds(&data, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
int a = htonl(32);
char *head = (char*)&a;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    qDebug() << QString::number(int((head[i]&0xff))+0x100, 16) << " ";
qDebug() << endl;
```

here, the output is "100 100 100 120", which is what I want.
Then I try to write it into data stream.

```
ds.writeRawData(head, 4);
char *buffer = new char[4];
ds.readRawData(buffer, 4);
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    qDebug() << QString::number(int((buffer[i]&0xff))+0x100, 16) << " ";
qDebug() << endl;
```

But here the output here is "100 100 100 100"

Am I having some misunderstanding about the usage of QDataStream?

Comment: You should use <cstdint>, and uint32_t, uint8_t and friends when doing work over the network which is when you are dealing with raw bytes. Relying on `int` and `long` to be sane is insane.

Comment: I have tried 'uint32_t a = htonl(32)', but the result is still the same...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should reset the position of the stream device by calling `ds.device()->reset();` before you attempt to read the data with `ds.readRawData()`.

`ds.readRawData()` will return the number of bytes that were read. If you check it, it is probably returning `0`.